# Select only video file using pickerview in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

How to select only video file using pickerview in iphone sdk?

Answer (score 2):

You can use UIImagePickerController class as below to select only videofiles from library

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;  
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```